# Place data into table using jquery

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, html-table

I am having trouble recreating the structure of a table after scraping data from another website. I am using the example found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/m4QCt/

An example of what I am trying to recreate is here: http://jsfiddle.net/curly33/v5h6G/

```
        $.each($foop.find('table.data tr'), function(idx, item) {

                mytext = $(item).children().remove().text();
                $('<td>'+mytext+'</td>').appendTo($('#divs tr'));

        });
```

The roster table is a perfect example of what I am trying to recreate. I just cannot think of a way to separate the data into individual td cells on separate table row lines instead of bunching all of the scraped data from each row into td cells.

Comment: did you think something like this?
$.each($foop.find('table.data tr'), function(idx, item) {
      $("#divs").append($(this));
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just loop through the cells of the scrapped **tr**? It will be something like:

```
$.each($foop.find('table.data tr'), function(idx, item) {
    var tr = $("<tr><td>a</td></tr>");
    $.each($(item).children(), function(index, cell) {
        tr.append('<td>' + $(cell).html() + '</td>');    
    });
    tr.appendTo($('#divs'));               
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/v5h6G/1/